# Boost::d_ary_heap_indirect DistanceMap template argument

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking at using `boost::d_ary_heap_indirect` in my code, but I'm having trouble understanding one of the template arguments, `DistanceMap`. The comments (full source availible [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/graph/detail/d_ary_heap.hpp)) have this to say:

```
// - DistanceMap must be a ReadablePropertyMap from Value to something
//   (typedef'ed as distance_type).
```

I tried looking at it's usage in boost classes, but when used in `boost::astar_search`, it is created by `detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<tag::rank_map, D>(D())(g, arg_pack)`, which I understand even less...

Looking at the source, I get the feeling it could be the priorities, but that seems wierd when called "distance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `DistanceMap` is a map from value to priority, aka key. D-ary heap is commonly used for *Dijkstra*'s algorithm. In *Dijkstra*'s algorithm, the priority is, especially, represented by the edge path cost(distance). I guess that's why its named like this.

E.g., there is a method `keys()` to return this map.

```
// return value-to-key map
DistanceMap keys() const
{
  return distance;
}
```